# how to add element into the nested vector

Tags: c++, vector

Hello sorry for the stupid question but I am very beginner in c++. I cannot describe the problem well because of my bad English. I'll add my code here that i have tried so far.

```
 vector< vector<string> >allData;

 int main(){
    vector<string>test;        
    for(int i = 0; i<allData.size(); i++){
        test = allData[i];
    }
    int id;
    cout<<"enter Id"<<endl;
    cin>>id;
    if (id == test[2]){
        string desc;
        cout<<"enter ur description"<<endl;
        cin>>description;
        allData.push_back(description);
    } else {
        cout<<"there is no data with the id u have entered"<<endl;
    }
 }
```

Above code is just an example code. Lets say that there are 2 vectors inside the vector named allData, so when i enter the ID of a first vector i can add description into the vector which i have chosen by choosing it by its Id. Somehow i cannot do that thing like choosing the first or second vector by inputing their ids then add more datas into chosen 1. So please someone tell me what should i do. I know that above code is incomplete and awful but as i said before i am very beginner in c++

Comment: It is very unclear what you are trying ask.  Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: A "nested" vector is just a vector. So, understand how a vector works.

Comment: okay i will try to do that i know its very unclear because i cannot describe it well.

Comment: I think you need an `std::map`...

Answer (score 1):

You can add values into nested vector just like a normal vector. So you could do `allData[i].push_back(description)` or even `allData[i][j] = description` to overwrite an existing value. However you are trying to push a string into `allData` which does not contain strings but rather Vectors of strings.

Additionally your first for loop runs through `allData` and saves each to `test`, overwriting `test` each time. When the loop is done test will simply contain the last element of `allData`. Thus your for loop is the equivalent of doing `test = allData.back()`

Comment: thank you very much i tried implementing like that but somehow i couldn't because when i enter the id of first child i have to enter its vector so that i can add a element inside that one

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. There are two answers here detailing access to nested vectors. You should go back and edit your question to make your intent if you want further help. What is the intent of the for loop? Why are you comparing to the 2 location? You declared a string called `desc` but later use it as `description`.

Comment: its not the actual code which i have implemented, its just a small part of the code that i wanted to implement now. I have a function where i declared age and name variable, which is used to store these 2 datas on vector so later i push_back this vector on the parent vector, so that i can add vector inside a vector dynamically. So now i want to pick a first or second vector by choosing it by its id so that i can add 1 more data on one of them. Is there anyway that i can contact you directly like send you message for further asistance. @Taus

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you need to access your child vectors directly, you need to declare your `vector` saying how many child vectors it has (without this, you have segmentation fault when trying to access it ie. `allData[0]` will be unitialised).

Let's say you have 2, so they will be `allData[0]` and `allData[1]`, just like a normal array.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> allData (2);

allData[0].push_back("string0a");
allData[0].push_back("string0b");
allData[1].push_back("string1");

for(auto & a : allData[0])
    std::cout << a << "\n";
```

Of course, you can add vectors dinamically too.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> allData;
std::vector<std::string> child0;
child0.push_back("string0");
allData.push_back(child0);
```

And to check if the id the user input is valid, you can do

```
if(id >= 0 && id < allData.size()) {
   ....
```

Comment: Thank you very much im gonna try that. Is it possible to add string into first child of the vector without declaring its childs like you suggested. I wanted to implement a function where user inputs the id of a first child of the vector so he can add 1 more element into the first child. Its like there are 2 person in the allData vector, each of them stored into separate vectors, each has their id, name, and age. So when i want to add 1 more element called description only on first person's vector. I cannot distinguish whether its first or second person by entering his id :(

Comment: @CrappyKOKO Are you using some sort of `struct` ? I'm sorry, but I really couldn't understand your problem. I think you should update your question  adding more information, so we can get a better understanding

Comment: No Im not using `struct` teacher told me to use vectors only to store the data, and display the datas from vector. And the parent vector have to be a dynamic to store more vectors inside it. The only problem i cant manage is I don't know how to add more element inside the first child or the second or third child when i enter their ids. I have a function where I add some strings into temporary vector then i push_back that temporary vector to parent vector called allData which is in the code.

Comment: @CrappyKOKO Allright. What's this id you are talking about ? Is it the index of nested vector ? If it is, wouldn't it be just `allData[id].push_back("moreElement");` ? And yes you can do this without declaring how many childs it will have, you just have to make sure this index exists (like I showed in my answer).

Comment: yes it is index of a nested vector. Each child vectors has ids so i was trying some codes but couldn't manage to pick the id of a nested vector and add more elements inside. Thank you very much for your help im gonna try more

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `all_data` is a vector of vectors representing rows and columns. You can create a scratch vector for a row, `push_back()` data on that scratch vector, then `push_back()` that scratch vector onto `all_data` like so:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> all_data;
   for (int ii = 0; ii < 10; ii++) {
      std::vector<int> row_data;
      for (int jj = 0; jj < 10; jj++) {
         row_data.push_back(ii * jj);
      }
      all_data.push_back(row_data);
   }
   return (0);
}
```